# Check if Capacitor App is installed from its web version

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, mobile, capacitor

I have an app that is running as both mobile app (iOS and Android, using Capacitor) and as normal website in browser (using Vue+Ionic) - both share a single code base.

To increase app usage, I would like to prompt the web user to open the page in App Store / Play Store, or open the app directly if it is installed using its URL.

What I can find until now is only `canOpenUrl()` from Capacitor's `AppLauncher` (https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/app-launcher#canopenurl). The issue is, I would like to do this check when user is on mobile browser only, and on web `AppLauncher` is not available.

Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do? And if it's not the normal use case, what kind of flow can I use alternatively?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the platform is native with `Capacitor.isNativePlatform();`

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/core-apis/web#isnativeplatform

Or check if the platform is web with `Capacitor.getPlatform() === 'web'`

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/core-apis/web#getplatform

Comment: but those are to simply check whether the user is on web or on mobile, isn't it? What I'm trying to achieve here is from the web, check if its corresponding mobile app is installed. Would that be technically possible?

Comment: You can’t know if the app is installed, you can only try to open it.